# How to block/restrict push to remote master totally

Tags: git, github, hook, githooks

- I want to restrict any kind of push from any branch to my master branch.
- I want to do all this from client-side
- For Example, I have 3 branches master mtest mtest2
- I don't want "git push -u origin master" to work from any of the branches.
- If I have checked out mtest but if I run by mistake "git push -u origin master" this should not work.

I wrote  the pre-push hook, but it only stops the push if the current branch is master
It doesn't work if you run "git push -u origin master" and you are in say mtest branch.
I also tried to see if we can get the push arguments so that we can know to which branch the push is directed but unfortunately, I didn't get that in the arguments received by the pre-push hook.

I need a way to block the push to master branch totally.
But the push to other branches must work as usual.

Any way to do that.

Comment: Try reading `sys.stdin` from your pre-push hook (read each line, print each line; run `git push origin branch1:branch2 branch3:master`, and become enlightened).

Comment: sys.stdin not returning anything..Am i missing anything here
Code :
print(sys.argv)

print("Below stdin")
for line in sys.stdin:
  print(line)

bytes = sys.stdin.read()
print(bytes)

$ git push -u origin master
['C:/python_stuff/my_repos/m_fullapp/m_full_app/.git/hooks/pre-push', 'origin', 'git@github.com:magic/m_full_app.git']
Below stdin

Git Version: git version 2.9.0.windows.1
Current Branch: mtest
Branch master set up to track remote branch master from origin.
Everything up-to-date

Comment: In this case, your Git called up their Git, determined that `git push origin master` did not need to do anything, and therefore did nothing. Your hook runs, but since no push happens, there are no input lines. Use a `git push` that actually causes things to happen on the server.

Comment: Thanks, @torek  for the explanation... That was the reason now it's working fine :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the docs on pre-push hooks, and the `.git/hooks/pre-push.sample` given with any repo :

information on the target references is passed through stdin, not through `sys.argv`

Comment: sys.stdin is not returning anything

Comment: sys.stdin not returning anything..Am i missing anything here
Code :
print(sys.argv)

print("Below stdin")
for line in sys.stdin:
  print(line)

bytes = sys.stdin.read()
print(bytes)

$ git push -u origin master
['C:/python_stuff/my_repos/m_fullapp/m_full_app/.git/hooks/pre-push', 'origin', 'git@github.com:magic/m_full_app.git']
Below stdin

Git Version: git version 2.9.0.windows.1
Current Branch: mtest
Branch master set up to track remote branch master from origin.
Everything up-to-date

Comment: The comment at the top of your script says you started with a `pre-commit` sample. Are you editing a pre-push, or a pre-commit hook ?

Comment: Its pre_push only ... i first edited pre_commit and copied the content to pre_push..Hence that pre_commit sample description is present. But the file name is pre_push only it is getting executed properly as i shared the output earlier but its not listing sys.stdin content.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the GitHub repository
2. Click `Settings`
3. Click `Branches` in the sidebar
4. Click `Add rule`
5. Enable `Require pull request reviews before merging` or `Require status checks to pass before merging`

Comment: Hi Nick thanks for the suggestion but I am looking for a client-side solution.
Can it be done from git config locally .. I tried few flags but it didn't work for me.
Is this possible via hook?

Comment: @Shell_Magic Client-side solution can be easily subverted. At least use client-side + server-side solution.

Comment: @phd yes but that's the requirement we have ... we want the restriction to be from the client-side ...we want to keep the hooks or whatever restriction from the client site without doing any change at the server-side. I am finding it difficult to find a client-side solution.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to "totally" block something from the client side. If the script runs on the client's computer, they can just delete the script and push whatever they want. You need a server side solution if you don't trust the user to follow your recommendations.

Comment: If the problem is that you don't want to have to edit GitHub settings, just write a GitHub Action in `.github/workflows` to fail the build on improper commits.